# Unescape последовательности вида "\U0001f973"

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения

У меня есть строка str = "\U0001f973". Это escape sequence для эмодзи . Я хочу получить в этой строке не escape sequence, а именно сам эмодзи.

Я не могу воспользоваться Regex.Unescape() - он работает только c \u.

Вот здесь есть код для решения этой проблемы, и он действительно работает для некоторых случаев: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40032496/how-to-unescape-a-sequence-include-u-and-u

Но в моем случае `char.ConvertFromUtf32(int.Parse("0001f973", NumberStyles.HexNumber))` возвращает ту же самую последовательность "\U0001f973". Я не знаю, почему это происходит.

Как мне сделать unescape?

Поясню: вот пример такого формата последовательности, которая конвертируется так, как я ожидаю, на выходе получаю эмодзи для книги. 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А вот дальше я беру свою строку, конвертирую, но получаю ту же последовательность. Почему так происходит? 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А как вы проверяете результат? Возможно, вы его случайно эскейпите обратно

Comment: @andreymal Я добавил пояснение с картинками, что я ожидаю и что получаю.

Comment: Так, то есть у вас  уже строка с эмоджи? `str = "\U0001f973"`? Не `str = @"\U0001f973"`? См. https://ideone.com/bbBrcv. *возвращает ту же самую последовательность* говорит о том, что строка у вас вовсе не та, что вы думаете.

Comment: @Wiktor Да, у меня уже строка с эмоджи. То есть "\U0001f973". Если сделать ToCharArray(), то получится два символа '\ud83e' и '\udd73'. Но дело даже не в этом, выше на картинках я пытаюсь сконвертировать 2 значения, и справа отладчик показывает, что внутри. В одном случае он отображает эмоджи, а в другом нет. Строка забита жестко и эти два выражения -- единственное, что есть. Может, у ConvertFromUtf32() есть какие-то нюансы?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В моём случае меня настораживало то, что в отладчике в поле value я видел для разных эмодзи либо код, либо сам эмодзи, потому что в дальнейшем по этому эмодзи я делал запрос к сервису с картинками. 
Я протестировал разные эмодзи и оказалось, что такое происходит, когда я беру эмодзи из Unicode новее, чем Unicode 8. Вот здесь есть таблица с версией Unicode для разных версий .Net.
А разница между "\U0001f973" и @"\U0001f973" понятна, спасибо.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score -1):

> У меня есть строка str = "\U0001f973". Это escape sequence для эмодзи . Я хочу получить в этой строке не escape sequence, а именно сам эмодзи.

Проблема в том, что escape sequence - это и есть представление "самого эмодзи", только в файле исходного кода. Строка str во время выполнения и будет содержать этот эмодзи. Ваш код для unescape правилен для ситуации, когда в строке было бы, допустим, `"\\U0001f973"`. В данном случае это просто не нужно.

Но вопрос - как проверить на практике, что в строке действительно нужный символ? Ведь в консоли шрифт с высокой вероятностью не позволит вывести эмодзи. Один из способов - сформировать HTML такого вида:

```
string str = "\U0001f973";
File.WriteAllText(
    "test.html",
    "<html><head><meta charset=\"utf-8\"/></head><body><p>Your string is: " + str+"</p></body></html>",
    Encoding.UTF8);
```

Тогда в любом современном браузере вы сможете увидеть его:

[image: screenshot]